Google mock dependency injection in fixture gives 'invalid new-expression of abstract class type' error
I am trying to create an example of how dependency injection can benefit the current code base I am working on. Part of the example is a demonstration of how DI can benefit the unit testability of the code.
In this example, a compile error is given that I have never seen before: https://godbolt.org/z/3xoKhefYs. I do understand that a virtual function must be implemented.
Looking at the googletest source, the following comment is given for the virtual function of "TestBody()": https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L326.
Did I miss anything with my implementation of the mock or test? I look forward to your ideas.
I tried the following example in Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/3xoKhefYs. My expectation is that it would compile and run. But the error given by the compiler seems to point out an implementation issue with the googletest framework.

Thank you for the comment. I renamed the "Test" class to "TestClass". This fixed the error. (How could I have not seen this...)

The [mre] must be inline in the question, and not placed on external sites.

The problem is that there are two classes called Test in scope of TestFixture: ::testing::Test (added as injected-class-name) and your ::Test in global scope. When compiler looks up Test, it first finds injected-class-name ::testing::Test and this is an abstract class.
The solution is simply to rename your struct Test to something else or use ::Test everywhere in TestFixture to make sure compiler chooses your class from global namespace.
